# Is there a way to bookmark pages on your phone?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I'd like to know if it is possible to somehow bookmark pages in GTA V. It would be nice if I could pull up my phone in online mode and be taken right away to my bank deposit page. Or even change the home page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as my experience, backed by a search through the game manual, goes there's **no** way to neither bookmark any page or change the homepage of your phone browser.

Comment: hope they have this feature in next update